# Minimal polynomial and annihilating polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question: Is minimal polynomial and annihilating polynomial of matrix have same irreducible factors?

I know that, characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial of matrix have same irreducible factors. 
But is same is true for annihilating polynomial? Can't able to prove this.

Comment: An annihilating polynomial is any multiple of the minimal polynomial. Why should the extra factor have the same irreducible factors as the minimal polynomial?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.